# python request cannot set the cookies on next request

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

Hey i'm trying to use python request for get authentication and get whole data after get authentication here my code:

```
       r = requests.session() 
       r.auth = ('admin','21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3')

    try:
        auth = {'username' : 'admin', 'password' : '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'}

        # first request, for login & get session
        response = r.post('http://' + 'localhost:8098' + '/login.do', data=auth)

        url = "http://localhost:8098/accTransactionToday.do"
        payload={
            'pageSize': '50',
            'list': ''
        }
        headers = {
            'Cookie': response.headers['Set-Cookie'],
            'Content-Type' : 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
        }
        cookies = dict(response.cookies)

        #second request, for get the data based on parameter after login
        response = r.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, cookies=cookies, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin','21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'))
        block = response.text.split('\n') 
    except :
        with requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
            print ("EXCEPTION : "), e 
        pass
    print(response)
```

i successfully get the session on the "login" :

```
cookies : <RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='SESSION', value='adfe220d-8bb4-46fc-939b-ee9aa928280f', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='', path_specified=False, secure=False, expires=None, discard=False, comment='', comment_url=False, rest={'HttpOnly': ''}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

but when i try to execute the next request ( which is will get in the 'response') it returns the cookie :

```
cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

am i wrong? because i need the cookies to get whole data, i had been tested the API's on postman and it successfully returned the data that i want

thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `requests.Session()` which is much cleaner. It handles cookies for you.

```py
session = requests.Session()

res = session.post(...) # Now cookies are saved from this request

# next request

session.post(...) # Cookies will still be stored from previous request
```

Comment: i'm sorry but the code above is using r = request.Session( ).

so on my code, i write the post request with using r.post ( ) and
is still same, but thankyou for the answer

Comment: So you are expecting a value in `response.cookies`? Have you checked `r.cookies` afterward?

Comment: yes i can get it on r.cookies, but when i execute the next request is still empty